# setup:static-content:deploy errors

Tags: magento-2.1

When ever i run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it outputs the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 15 passed to
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy::__construct() must be of the
>   type array, null given, called in
>   /vagrant/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on l ine 93 and defined in
>   /vagrant/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Deploy/LocaleDeploy.php:177

with the stack trace of:

> 0
>   /vagrant/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy->__construct(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput),
>   Object(Magento\Translation\Model\Js\Config), Object
>   (Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\RepositoryFactory),
>   Object(Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManagerFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\RequireJs\ConfigFactory), Object(Magento\Fra
>   mework\App\View\Asset\Publisher),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager), Object(Ma in
>   /vagrant/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Deploy/LocaleDeploy.php
>   on line 177

This is with Magento 2.1.7.

**Update:**
I did a fresh install and it turns out if you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` before you run `setup:static-content:deploy` it causes the error.

Comment: It is sad to see users who ask a question & never come to see the answers

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a user permission issue on your vagrant. Try `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a fresh installation, then it is surely a **permissions** issue

First of all, you'd know what is the group of your webserver user (typically www-data, if you use Apache)

Then you'd add your user (the one who owns the files and folders, and the one who executes bin/magento console commands) to webserver group. *A trick to make things easier is adding the webserver user to your user group too*

You can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group) more info about managing users & groups in Linux

And then, in your Magento root folder, run this commands (in a Linux server, which is the most common case)

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

You can find [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) precise info about that